# When Spring Reads xml confriguation files excactly?

Tags: spring

Can some one help me on the topic that when spring reads all xml files that are present in different different jars in my production enviroment? i mean to say does reading occur at first autwiring of  a component or at the time of first request to Dispacher servlet ot at the time of servlet context initiALISATION?

Comment: Are you using any xml to define the bean?

Comment: Spring creates the bean factory and reads all configuration during context initialization.  It's the only time that makes sense.  Please - one question mark per question will do.

Comment: Thanks . In my Project I Have war file that depends on 10-15 different Jars i mean the internal classes of that war takes DI of other Jars that have their own spring Configuration files defined . Now as In my war i have configured spring MVC in which i have imported 10 different spring configuration files of beans present in my war . Will spring scans all jars (my war helper libraries present in my war) as well as my war at the time of context initialisation and saves info about all inter dependencies or Just scan my war classes and scan libraries on first DI in war any of the war class??

Comment: Will some one please clear my doubt???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Context initialisation take place in very start phase of a spring based project . If all spring beans present anywhere in the classpath are initialised properly without any error a Spring application is ready to serve . All spring sigelton beans wired with each other serve the executing request